# Views caching dont show changes

Tags: views, 7, caching

I'm having a problem with views and caching. Within a custom module, i do changes on my database, which is working fine, but my view won't show that changes until I clear all caches.

I tried to deactivate views-caching here "admin/structure/views/settings/advanced"
Caching in the view is deactivated too
And the whole caching is deactivated here "admin/config/development/performance"

But I still have to clear all caches on every change I make to see what I did. Is there a chance to stop caching for that view by code in the module? Or any other possibility?

EDIT: I now tried a module called "CacheExclude" and

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = 0;
drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);
$conf['cache'] = FALSE;
```

but no change :(

EDIT 2:
Here is the code where I change the field in the database:

```
foreach($books as $book) {
    $query = db_update('field_data_field_zuordnung')
        ->fields(array(
            'field_zuordnung_value' => 'verkauft',
            ))
        ->condition('entity_id', $book->product_id, '=')
        ->execute();
}
```

The change is done in the DB, but it isn't shown in the view. After that, I use drupal_goto to move to a "you're done site".

Comment: You might want to give a bit more detail of what your module does so we can maybe thing of other reasons you are facing the problem.

Comment: I am changing a custom field. In the first place I have a variable in that field, after my action, this variable changes. But this change is only visible after I clear my cache. I'm putting some code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally be using the [Field Attach API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7) to avoid these problems.

Or for a quick solution have a look at [field_attach_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) where at the end of the function, it clears the field cache:

```
$entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
if ($entity_info['field cache']) {
  cache_clear_all("field:$entity_type:$id", 'cache_field');
}
```

Comment: +1 If you don't use the API then relevant hooks won't be invoked which might break functionality provided by other modules (now or in the future).